# How to filter data from a state, based on what the user types in an input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create the functionality, where an API fetches data and displays them in a list. When the user types in the input, the data that matches each key stroke is then displayed. The functionality works, but here is the bug I am running into: I only want to initially display 3 items from the api, then when the user clicks the "view more" button, it displays the entire list. However, if the user doesn't press the "view more" button and they type in the input, it only filters through the 3 items that are initially displayed, and doesn't filter through the entire api data.

```
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
const [viewAllRoles, setViewAllRoles] = useState(false);
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState("");
const searchValue = useRef("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://advisoryalpha.github.io/skill-assessments/identities.json")
      .then((res) => {
        setApiData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

return (

 const viewRolesHandler = () => {
    setViewAllRoles(!viewAllRoles);
  };

<>
   <input
      type="text"
      ref={searchValue}
      value={filterData}
      onChange={(e) => setFilterData(e.target.value)}
   >
   </input>
   <ul>
     <ShowDataLength
       apiData={apiData}
       filterData={filterData}
       viewAllRoles={viewAllRoles}
   />
     <button
       id="view-all__btn"
       style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "5px" }}
       onClick={viewRolesHandler}
     >
       {!viewAllRoles ? "View all" : "View less"}
     </button>
   </ul>
)
</>

ShowDataLength component:

const ShowDataLength = ({
  apiData,
  filterData,
  setName,
  setRole,
  viewAllRoles,
}) => {
  function dataHandler() {
    return !viewAllRoles ? apiData.slice(0, 3) : apiData;
  }

  return dataHandler()
    .filter(
      (el) =>
        el.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterData.toLowerCase()) ||
        filterData === ""
    )
    .map((el, index) => (
      <li
        key={index}
        onClick={() => {
          setName(el.name);
          setRole(el.role);
        }}
      >
        <h4>{el.name}</h4>
        <h5>{el.role}</h5>
      </li>
    ));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you're well. I think you not get filtered items. So first make some changes in input.

```
onChange={(e) => setFilterData(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
```

As this helps you to change lowercase during input.
Next make axios response easy like (advice, if you don't use it then no worry)-

```
const respones = await axios...(here is your code to fetch api)..
```

this will save data in response.

```
response&&response?.filter((search)=>(search.includes(FilterData)))
```

this code first check is there any data in response. if data inside response then it will apply filter. above response is data from api. you can change with your component that shows api data or for data for filtration.
To make above code more accurate then,

```
response&& response?.filter((filter)=>{
if(filterData.length>0){
return filter?.includes(filterData)
}else{
return filter
}
})
```

This code will always send data else it's available or not.

Why I add toLowerCase() in input? because ReactJs behave annoying when using tolowercase in filter that's why i prefer to use tolowercase when sending data to state.

If you still face any issue letme i will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning a filter from your dataHandler function

```js
function dataHandler() {
    return !viewAllRoles ? apiData.slice(0, 3) : apiData;
  }

// since viewAllRoles is false, it only grabs the first 3 from your list and filters them
  return dataHandler()
    .filter(
      (el) =>
        el.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterData.toLowerCase()) ||
        filterData === ""
    )
```

Instead, you should be able to just modify your dataHandler function and have the results you expect

```js
function dataHandler() {
    // If the user has typed a query, return all elements to filter through all
    if(filterData) return apiData;
    // Otherwise, return 3
    return !viewAllRoles ? apiData.slice(0, 3) : apiData;
}
```